# ElasticSearch - Why significant performance difference in search performance when using GET v/s POST?

Tags: elasticsearch

Our test result indicates. that when we execute search query using HTTP POST yields far better performance compared to HTTP GET.

I am trying to find out what are the reasons for this behavior.

I would appreciate any pointers/reasons to explain this behaior

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing something strange. It's exactly the same code which is executed with GET or POST on the _search endpoint.

You should update your question with more details (exact commands).